# Why do I need to require 'mail' on top of controller to use it outside ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I noticed that `Mail` gem doesn't get loaded outside `ActionMailer` context, but the gem is present in the proper gem group of `Gemfile` and then "loaded" upon Rails initialization.

To create a Mail object in a controller using `Mail.new` I need to put

```
require 'mail'
```

at the top of `example_controller.rb`, before

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
```

Could someone explain to me why?

#### Background:

I need to build an app whose functionality is primarily based on receiving emails of various types. I need to expose only one email address, where people will send all of these emails.

My mail server will pipe the raw email to a ruby script that sends the raw email as a POST request to my app.

Then, I need to identify which kind of email has arrived inferring that from its content (primarily attachments).

For example, let's have emails of types `A`, `B` and `C`. My email processing function will call one of three methods once it identifies the type of the email.

Where should I put the processing function?

Comment: Downvoters please post why did you downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating mail objects in your controllers. You should create a mailer and then call that mailer from your controller to send any emails you need to.

For example, say you have the following mailer in `app/mailers/customer_mailer.rb`:

```
class CustomerMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_reminder(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: 'Reminder'
  end
end
```

You can then call this from your controller as needed:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    CustomerMailer.send_reminder(@user).deliver_now
  end
end
```

This way your controller can focus on the implementations specific to controlling the request, and leave the mailer to worry about how to send email.

It's worth noting you also have access to a `deliver_later` method if you're using a background job runner.

Take a look at the documentation for more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: The fact is that the email content is received via HTTP Post from a mail server that executes a script. Then, I need to process that mail, and change the behaviour because of its content. I **don't** send emails with that info. I need to process it. Maybe calling `mailer.receive(email)`?

Comment: You could have made your question a little more specific! The thing is, controllers should not be manipulating data or making any decisions based upon it. Business logic such as that belongs in a model or a service object, depending on your particular context.

Comment: It seems that service objects would do the trick. Anyway, I will need to `require 'mail'`, won't I?

Comment: I think your previous suggestion of using `SomeMailer.receive(raw_email)` would be preferable to requiring `mail` on something else.

Comment: A final thought, my email processing is very big and has a lot of possibilities, having to call different methods, because there are a lots of possible emails that can arrive, and I need to infer its "type" from its content. Should I process that on a service and then call the adequate `Mailer.receive`?

Comment: Without knowing the exact requirements you're talking about it would be impossible to say for sure. However if you take something like an online shop for example, they might receive emails relating to pending orders and product reviews. The mailer should be able to identify the type of request or pass it to a service object which can do the same. At that point you can call a `Product.receive_review` or `Order.receive_customer_feedback` method to handle the associated business logic. Something along those lines ought to work.